# Python Write to Record to New Text File

Tags: python, pyodbc

The code below is writing each record to a single text file. I would like to create a new text file for each record. Is there a way that I can append a unique character or number to the file name to coerce a new file?

```
import pyodbc
import csv

# Create connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}",server="<server>",database="<database>",uid="<username>",pwd="<password>")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM <table>")
row = cursor.fetchall()

with open(r"c:/Projects/record.txt", "w") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(row)
```

Comment: This code looks mostly reasonable for the described scenario - are you getting an error?  If so, please include it.  If not, please explain what trouble you're encountering (or what your actual question is).

Comment: The code above is writing each record to a single text file. I would like to create a new text file for each record. Is there a way that I can append a unique character or number to the file name to coerce a new file?

Comment: @localhost Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34212789/edit) your question and include that information as it is *very* relevant. As it reads right now, your question effectively communicates, "I want to learn something. Here is some code."

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can append a unique character or number to the file name to coerce a new file?

Yes, of course there is. Just iterate through the rows and build a different file name for each iteration. For example,

```python
import csv
import pyodbc

connStr = (
    r"Driver={SQL Server};"
    r"Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;"
    r"Database=myDb;"
    r"Trusted_connection=yes;"
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

sql = """\
SELECT 101 AS numthing, 'foo' AS txtthing
UNION ALL
SELECT 102 AS numthing, 'bar' AS txtthing
UNION ALL
SELECT 103 AS numthing, 'baz' AS txtthing
"""
crsr.execute(sql)
i = 1
for row in crsr:
    with open('C:/__tmp/Projects/record{0}.csv'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerow(row)
        i += 1
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

creates the sequentially-numbered files

record1.csv
record2.csv
record3.csv